# Dynamic ng-model value is not working for two way data binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am very new to angular js.

i created the form using dynamic fields .there i need to create dynamic ng-model value like Field[lable.LabelID] here lable.LabelID is dynamic value

this is my template page

```
 <form ng-submit="" ng-controller="saveOrder">
  <table class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
     <tr ng-repeat="lable in Grp.Label">
       <td style="width:30%" class="no-wrap text-left col-xs-text-center text-primary">
        <h4>{{lable.LabelName}}</h4>
       </td>
       <td style="width:60%" class="no-wrap  text-left">
           <input type="{{input_type[lable.InputType]}}" 
           name="{{lable.LabelID}}" ng-model="Field[lable.LabelID]" 
            ng-init="Field[lable.LabelID] = Field[lable.LabelID] || {}"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

and my controller is like

```
 productApp.controller('saveOrder',function($scope,$http)
{
    $scope.FieldOptions = {};
    $scope.createOrder = function()
    {
       alert("in");
       console.log($scope);
       console.log($scope.Field[1]); 
       console.log($scope.FieldOptions);
    }

 });
```

My Server Data will come like

```
{
   "GroupName": "Order Form",
   "Label": [
     {
        "InputType": "1",
        "LabelID": "1",
        "LabelName": "BillingDetails"
     },
     {
        "InputType": "1",
        "LabelID": "2",
        "LabelName": "shipping Details"
     }
    ]
 }
```

For that scenario am getting error like

```
  TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined

at Function.v.assign (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:73:162)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:72:33
at Object.e.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:88:347)
at pre (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:145:309)
at i (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:43:396)
at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:39:307)
at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:39:324)
at e (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:39:324)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:38:372
at Object.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js:148:122) <input type="{{input_type[lable.InputType]}}" name="{{lable.LabelID}}" ng-model="Field[lable.LabelID]" ng-init="Field[lable.LabelID] = Field[lable.LabelID] || {}" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

these type of questions i found lot in so. but i am unable to figuring out solution for my scenario. please help me with this issue...

any type of help is appreciable.

Comment: Where yo do you set your Grp.Label ?

Comment: i am getting all those data from server call like in this format  {
    "GroupName": "Order Form",
    "Label": [
        {
            "InputType": "1",
            "LabelID": "1",
            "LabelName": "BillingDetails"
        },
        {
            "InputType": "1",
            "LabelID": "2",
            "LabelName": "shipping Details"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Did you try setting `$scope.Field = [];` in the controller and removing the ng-init directives?

Comment: @CorySilva yes. i tried but same error ..                     TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined

Comment: @CorySilva i tried with $scope.Field = []; now its working fine ..thank you bro....

Comment: How is it working? what is `input_type` in `{{input_type[lable.InputType]}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `$scope.Field = [];` inside the controller and removing the `ng-init` directive.  In you current code, when compilation occurs `$scope.Field` is  getting undefined.